# Value does not fall within the expected range with "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException",

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I use the join query in sharepoint. but it's seem i get an error on the  when i get value from the Lookup lists.

Here is my design

- Document as a Document Library type have a Id

  ```
  Id | DocLeafRef
  ---+-------------
  1  | Document A
  2  | Document B
  ```
- Activities list, have a foreign key 'e8_document' that reference to the Document Id

  ```
  Id | e8_document | Name
  ---+-------------+-----------
  1  | 1           | Activity A
  2  | 1           | Activity B
  3  | 1           | Activity C
  4  | 2           | Activity D
  ```

Here is the result that I need to get.

```
Id | e8_document | Name       | DocLeafRef
---+-------------+--------------------------
1  | 1           | Activity A | Document A
2  | 1           | Activity B | Document A
3  | 1           | Activity C | Document A
4  | 2           | Activity D | Document B
```

Could any one please help me what's wrong in my query. Here is my query

```
<View>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name = 'DocLeafRef'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'ID'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'e8_document'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'Title'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'Author'/>
    <FieldRef Name = 'Created'/>
  </ViewFields>
  <Joins>
    <Join Type = 'INNER' ListAlias = 'Documents'>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name ='e8_document' RefType = 'Id'/>
         <FieldRef Name ='ID' List ='Documents'/>
      </Eq>
    </Join>
  </Joins>
  <ProjectedFields>
    <Field ShowField ='FileLeafRef' Type ='Lookup' Name ='DocLeafRef' List ='Documents'/>
  </ProjectedFields>
  <Query>
     <Where>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='e8_caseId'></FieldRef>
           <Value Type = 'Number'>23</Value>
        </Eq>
     </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

And here is the exception
[image: Value does not fall within the expected range]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the problem is that `FileLeafRef` is not one of the field types that can be used in a projected field.

Refer to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx).

> Only the following types of fields can be included in a ProjectedFields element:
>
> •Calculated (treated as plain text)
>
> •ContentTypeId
>
> •Counter
>
> •Currency
>
> •DateTime
>
> •Guid
>
> •Integer
>
> •Note (one-line only)
>
> •Number
>
> •Text

Comment: Any way to get other field types that ProjectedFields does not support like UniqueId (lookup type) and FileLeafRef (File type)?

Comment: You could use a workflow to automatically copy the desired field value to a text field, then expose that text field in your projection.

Comment: Do you have any example ?